# Why my jq treats null as a proper value while parsing json via jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have json which looks like this

```
{
  "phx4fo": {
    "db_name": "phx4fo",
    "db_unique_name": "phx4fo",
    "db_crs_state": "OFFLINE",
    "db_sid_list": "phx4fo1,phx4fo2",
    "db_host_list": "epxa25-swlke1,epxa25-swlke2",
    "db_home": "/u02/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2"
  },
  "phx68r": {
    "db_name": "phx68r",
    "db_unique_name": "phx68r",
    "db_crs_state": "OFFLINE",
    "db_sid_list": "phx68r1,phx68r2",
    "db_host_list": "epxa25-swlke1,epxa25-swlke2",
    "db_home": "/u02/app/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/dbhome_6"
  }}
```

In some cases, dbname is present and in some cases, it is not. Now, I want if dbname is not present then it should exit code without doing anything.My code is:-

```
IFS=, read -r -a SIDLIST <<<"$(jq -r ".\"$dbname\".db_sid_list" $CRSOUT)"
    for SIDVAL in $SIDLIST;do
        if [[ ! -z "$SIDVAL" ]];then
             CHECK_SID=$(ps -eawf|grep smon|grep ^oracle|grep -v grep|grep -v ASM|grep -v perl|cut -d"_" -f3| grep $ORA_DB_NAME | grep -w $SIDVAL )
             if [[ ! -z "$CHECK_SID" ]];then
                ORACLE_SID=$CHECK_SID
                break
             fi
            fi
    done
```

But instead of exit it is proceeding further

Comment: There is a mismatch between the problem description and the sample JSON, in which all the inner objects have a "dbname" key that matches the name of the key of the enclosing object.  Also your jq query does not make much sense,  as it uses "$dbname" but there is no such variable.  Please review the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: I have one variable named dbname like this 
dbname=$(echo $1|cut -d'=' -f2)

Comment: These details belong in the question, not in the comments.  Also, you still have not followed the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

In the comment, you seem to indicate that there is one value of `$dbname`, so the following should help:

```
dbname=phx4fo
CRSOUT=input.json
jq -r --arg dbname "$dbname" '(.[$dbname] // empty) |.db_sid_list' "$CRSOUT"
```

With your sample JSON, the above results in:

```
phx4fo1,phx4fo2
```

Presumably you will want to split on the comma, which can be done within the same jq query, e.g. by modifying it to:

```
(.[$dbname] // empty) | .db_sid_list/"," | .[]
```

---

By the way, if you are going to use `read -a`, then you will need to understand shell arrays, and modify your shell script accordingly.  I would suggest you break down your problem into small pieces that you can solve independently, so that it will be easier to construct a complete solution.

Comment: Basically i want to quit at the time if value of SIDVAL is null but it is not exiting from the program and it treats null as authentic value

Comment: That’s why I added `// empty’

Comment: .empty works for me thank you